# Android use notch (status bar) area in fullscreen

Tags: java, android

I am currently making a gallery app and I want to use the full screen for displaying my images. For this I would have to use the Notch area on my Oneplus 6T as well, which I cannot get to work. Ever source I've looked at said to use `windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode` which doesn't seem to work for me and the Notch area is still blacked out and unused by the app. I have totally run out of ideas of how to fix this and cannot find any more results on the internet.

App Theme:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Raspjannis" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pastelBlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/iconBlue</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/iconBlue</item>

    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/iconBlue</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/pastelBlue</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <!-- Backgrounds Theme -->
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/pastelBlue</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="cardForegroundColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="editTextBackground">@color/bright</item>

    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="p">
        shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, or never -->
    </item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Raspjannis.NoActionBar.splashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.Raspjannis.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme">

</style>

<style name="Theme.Raspjannis.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.Raspjannis">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Raspjannis.NoStatusBar">
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="p">
        shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, or never -->
    </item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Raspjannis.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.Raspjannis.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- This style is where you define the tint color of your overflow menu button -->
<style name="actionOverflowButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/dark</item>
</style>

<style name="menuItem" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="icons" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/dark</item>

</style>
```

And here is the code that sets the theme and fullscreen:

```
public static void hideSystemUI(Activity activity) {
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Raspjannis_NoStatusBar);

}

public static void showSystemUI(Activity activity) {
    activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Raspjannis);
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
```

Comment: Notch area, do you mean status bar?

Comment: Yes i do mean the status bar

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e

Comment: FWIW I draw behind the status bar in my apps and I've never heard of `windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode` before